# Indexing hierarchical columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with hierarchical columns and I am trying to figure out how to index.  How do I adopt the dataframe basic index `df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]` when there are 4 levels of column index?  I am looking for some strategy like `df.loc['2014-01-02', DK='18757']` ... How can I access the data there?  How can I access the column names below a given column level -- return 'App_Field' names where 'DeviceType' = 'Meter', or return 'Fields' where 'DK' = '20653'?

```
>>> df
DeviceType            Meter         Inverter                   \
DK                    18757            20178            20179   
Field            Generation     Inverter_Gen     Inverter_Gen   
App_Field  generation_cumul generation_cumul generation_cumul   
2014-01-01              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-02              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-03              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-04              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-05              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-06              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-07              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-08              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-09              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-10              NaN              NaN              NaN   

DeviceType                         Weather                       
DK                    20180          20653                       
Field          Inverter_Gen     Irradiance             CellTemp  
App_Field  generation_cumul irradiance_avg cell_temperature_avg  
2014-01-01              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-02              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-03              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-04              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-05              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-06              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-07              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-08              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-09              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-10              NaN            NaN                  NaN  

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: To clarify, I understand that I can burn my way down, eg: `df['Weather']['20653']['Irradiance']` ... but is there an option akin to `df[:]['20653']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert every level of columns into a Series, then you can use boolean mask to select what you want.

```
a = list("EEEETTTT")
b = list("11223344")
c = list("XYXYXYXY")
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(a,b,c), names=["A","B","C"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 8)), columns=mi)

A, B, C = [pd.Series(mi.get_level_values(name)) for name in mi.names]
mask = (A=="T") & (B.isin(["2","3"]))
df.iloc[:, mask.values]
```

Comment: this is on tap for 0.14: and should be a general solution, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6134